# Running server against database whose datafiles are created in external hard disk

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have created the `datafiles` in an external hard disk for a particular db . When the hard disk is connected I am able to run the server without any issues . Now when I remove the hard disk and try running the server , it throws error saying

> NO DATAFILE PATH Found

This is because the path of `datafiles` is in the external hard disk .

Now, is there anyway i can run the server against the same database even if the hard disk is not connected ?

Comment: The database is what is on the disk, if the disk isn't available it essentially doesn't exist. You can sort of run [an *instance*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/startup.htm#CNCPT005) without the disk, with some work (I think), but it wouldn't have the data available, so would be pointless. So... what you're asking doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the real question is how to get the external disk datafiles onto the local system, have a look here :

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dfiles005.htm

Outline steps:

Procedure for Renaming Datafiles in a Single Tablespace

To rename datafiles in a single tablespace, complete the following steps:

1. Take the tablespace that contains the datafiles offline. The database must be open.

For example:

```
ALTER TABLESPACE users OFFLINE NORMAL;
```

2. Rename the datafiles using the operating system - in your case COPY the files from the external disk to local disk
3. Use the ALTER TABLESPACE statement with the RENAME DATAFILE clause to change the filenames within the database.

For example, the following statement renames the datafiles /u02/oracle/rbdb1/user1.dbf and /u02/oracle/rbdb1/user2.dbf to/u02/oracle/rbdb1/users01.dbf and /u02/oracle/rbdb1/users02.dbf, respectively:

```
ALTER TABLESPACE users
    RENAME DATAFILE '/u02/oracle/rbdb1/user1.dbf',
                    '/u02/oracle/rbdb1/user2.dbf'
                 TO '/u02/oracle/rbdb1/users01.dbf', 
                    '/u02/oracle/rbdb1/users02.dbf';
```

Always provide complete filenames (including their paths) to properly identify the old and new datafiles. In particular, specify the old datafile name exactly as it appears in the DBA_DATA_FILES view of the data dictionary.

4. Back up the database. After making any structural changes to a database, always perform an immediate and complete backup.